# How do I minimize latency caused by event polling in Psychopy?

Tags: python, real-time, polling, psychopy, low-latency

I need my `win.flip()` call as much close to being real-time as possible. Meanwhile, while waiting for the trigger to occur, which flips the buffer, I also want some keyboard keypresses to be listened for. So, which one is faster:

- assigning `event.globalKeys.add()` and relying on pyglet's thread to poll it
- or manually checking for `len(event.getKeys())` in my trigger callback?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the new Keyboard class which can plug into either the ioHub event polling system or the Psychtoolbox engine for event polling. Both of those poll the keyboard on a separate process independent of the rendering loop and timestamp the keypresses at source. Calls to `event.getKeys()` use pyglet and then polling occurs only once per screen refresh, at least during dynamic updating.

We would typically recommend, however, that you simply create studies in the Builder which will automatically use the current best practice and methods so you don't have to keep abreast of what the latest recommendations are.

Comment: it seems Keyboard class uses busy polling (is i use `Keyboard.waitForPresses()`), although in a separate process - which is aimed at minimal latency possible for registering the keypress itself; in my case, i believe polling once per screen refresh is preferable because flipping the buffer is more prioritized, and i don't care about keyboard latencies here

Comment: The title rather suggested that you cared about reducing latency. Once-per-refresh polling gives you a latency that can be as large as the screen refresh. If that doesn't matter for your needs then you can use any method you like - the additional lags and variability will be tiny compared with that introduced by the once-per-refresh polling

Comment: what i meant by latency is the latency of flipping the buffer. i need it to never miss the nearest refresh

Answer (score 0):

at first implemented the same with infinite `while True` loop listening for key that will never be pressed - just to make `globalKeys` constantly active, but then realised `event.waitKeys` will be polling during all my experiment - which i do not want
so, i made a function instead which will be checking all my global keys and calling related functions of my experiment when needed, and there will be `len(event.getKeys())` in some places inside them, when i want a possibility to suspend the procedure

```
def my_fun():
    while trigger == False:
        #doing main experiment functionality
        if len(event.getKeys()):
           listen_for_keypresses()
    return

def listen_for_keypresses():
    print('...ready for input')
    keys_pressed = event.waitKeys(clearEvents=False)
    if 'escape' in keys_pressed[0]:
        input_pressed = input('Confirm exit y/n')
        if input_pressed == 'y':
            win.close()
            logging.flush()
            io.quit()
            core.quit()
            return
    elif 'r' in keys_pressed[0]:
        my_fun()
        return
    listen_for_keypresses()
    return
listen_for_keypresses()
```